# Use always UTC+0 - Fix custom timezone on client browser with javascript / angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, object

How can I fix a custom timezone on client browser with javascript ?

For example, on angular I have a date "2015-10-16T00:00:00.000Z" from a backoffice.

I would like to have a display (with UTC-4 New York or with UTC+2 France), always : 16/10/2015

**Read :**

If I use the UTC on New York, I have : 15/10/2015.

```
<p ng-bind="(myDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy')"></p>
```

**Write :**

I modified the date prototype toJSON to delete timezone :

```
// Remove TimeZone
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){
    return moment(this).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000Z';
};
```

Comment: You should show us some code... How are you displaying that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this :

```
// Add timeZone
Date.prototype.addTimeZone = function () {
    if(this.getTimezoneOffset() > 0){
        this.setMinutes(this.getTimezoneOffset());
    }

    return this;
};
```

And this on my controller/model :

```
    new Date(myDate).addTimeZone();
```

**To resume :**

**extend-date-prototype.js**

```
// Add timeZone
Date.prototype.addTimeZone = function () {
    if(this.getTimezoneOffset() > 0){
        this.setMinutes(this.getTimezoneOffset());
    }

    return this;
};

// Remove TimeZone
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){
    return moment(this).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000Z';
};
```

**view.html**

```
<p ng-bind="(myDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy')"></p>
```

**controller.js**

```
new Date(myDate).addTimeZone();
```

I use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to get the offset of the client, then simple math

```
var dateToTranslate = new Date("2015-10-16T00:00:00.000Z");
var timezoneOffset = dateToTranslate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
var newDate = new Date(+dateToTranslate+timezoneOffset);
// Fri Oct 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) in my browser
```

Comment: Considering Summer Time in Europe for example, that would not work. In Germany, you have UTC+1 in winter and UTC+2 in summer time. So you would need to make that difference, too.

Comment: `getTimezoneOffset` may return different value if DST changes

Comment: @molerat I updated the code, don't know how I missed that, I guess it should be ok.